# Strange behavior UISearchBar on Iphone6

Tags: ios, ios8, uisearchbar, iphone-6

In my app i need to have a UISearchBar inside a cell.

Everything works fine, except in the iPhone6. Where lines appear in the search´s background.

[image]

Any idea why this and only in the iPhone6´s model?
My configuration is:

- Search Style: Prominent
- Bar Style: Default
- Translucent:NO
- BarTint:WhiteColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i change the style of the searchbar to minimal it removes the lines, but also it mess my custom colors. The solution i found was to add a clear color to the backgroundImage and set the desired color:

```
_seachBar.backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
_seachBar.backgroundColor = kColor_App_LightGray;
```

It´s work now, but i still don't have a explanation to this strange behavior only on the iPhone6. Any better solution or advise will be well receive. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just try changing the "search style" of the UISearchBar as "Minimal". I faced a similar kinda issue and I resolved it by changing style from "Default" to "Minimal".

Comment: it remove the lines, but i need to customize the search bar: textfield in white and the background in gray. How can i achieve this with a style in minimal?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to remove the background view of searchBarItem

```
for (UIView *backGroundView in self.searchBarItem.subviews)
    {
        if ([backGroundView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString
             (@"UISearchBarBackground")])
        {
            [backGroundView removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }
```